# Attach emoji reaction to incoming webhooks or slash commands in Slack

Tags: webhooks, emoji, slack

I would like to a send a message into Slack and automatically add a reaction. I dont mean the emoji within a message, but the reactions below:

[image]

I've read the API documentation at it offers a bunch of ways to style the message, even adding buttons. [Example Message](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22This%20is%20a%20line%20of%20text.%5CnAnd%20this%20is%20another%20one.%20%3Asmile%3A%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%7D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22%2336a64f%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Another%20optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%22Add%20buttons%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22game%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Chess%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22chess%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22game%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Falken%27s%20Maze%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22maze%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D):

[image]

I can not find any way to attach reactions however. Is there any way to add reactions automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you can not add reactions directly as part of an incoming webhook or response to a Slash command.

Instead you need to call the API method [`reactions.add`](https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.add) to add reactions to an item in Slack, which can be a message.

To make that work with slash commands, I would suggest posting your message with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) instead of using the slash command response. That way you get the timestamp of the message, which you can then use to add reactions.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to add a reaction to a message the slack bot has just sent.

```
def send_a_message(message, channel):
    message_info = sc.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel=channel,
        text=message,
        username='Slack Bot',
        icon_emoji=':robot_face:'
    )

    sc.api_call("reactions.add", name="robot_face", channel=channel, timestamp=message_info['ts'])
```